# SQL query for PL/SQL scripting

Tags: plsqldeveloper

I am writing a PL/SQL Procedure on SQL Developer, and I am running the below query :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||' into var_NumRec where COMPANY = '||var_company||' order by COMPANY';
OR
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||' into '||var_NumRec||' where COMPANY = '||var_company||' order by COMPANY';
```

I am getting error "SQL command not properly ended"

The below query is working fine, but I have to add the "where" clause to this query:

```
select count(*) from '||var_Table into var_NumRec;
```

Comment: What's the question? Where is the error? Where you got stuck? Please clarify what's the question and where is the error thrown. Avoid editing this post or asking again before reading [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: When I use the below query, I am getting the error "SQL command not properly ended" 
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||' into var_NumRec where COMPANY = '||var_company||' order by COMPANY'; 

I am passing table name as well as other 2 values as parameters

Answer (score 1):

I have checked the procedure and running below code , which is working fine.

```
DECLARE 
    var_NumRec NUMBER(15); 
    var_Table VARCHAR2(40); 
    var_company VARCHAR2(25) := 'ABC'; 
    TYPE 
        my_nested_table 
        IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40); 
    var_Direct my_nested_table := my_nested_table ('Employee', 'Accounts', 'FEE'); 
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN 1.. var_direct.count 
    LOOP 
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Direct(1) ||' where 1=1' into var_NumRec ;  
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ABC : '||var_NumRec); 
    END LOOP;
END;
```

You are using identifier "Company" which is invalid here, so earlier code was not running.

Comment: What my script doing is, I have some table that has "company" as column. I want to get the count from those tables where company(company name) = 'ABC'. And need to write another query to get count from the tables where company !='ABC'
The above query is giving me count of all the record. But I need the count of company='ABC'

Comment: Sorry! But I didn't understand your problem.

Comment: I want to get the record count from each table ['Employee', 'Accounts', 'FEE'] that having 'company' column data as 'ABC'. Basically, pl/sql query for "select count(*) from Employee where company='ABC' order by company. Since there are more tables that also has the 'company' column, I am trying to loop the query (to avoid writing the same query so many times) , keeping the table names in an array(nested table) and pass the table name as a variable to the query. But when I add 'where' condition to the query, it is giving me the error.

Comment: The one you suggested will give all the records count, not just company='ABC'
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Direct(1) ||' where 1=1' into var_NumRec ;

Comment: I found the issue. The query should be like this:
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Direct(i)||' where company = '''||var_company||''' Order by company 'into var_numrec;
I think for passing string values in where clause we should add '''| |'''
Thanks for the help and quick response

Answer (score 0):

Use below query in place of your execute immediate in pl SQL procedure :

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||'  where COMPANY = '||var_company order by COMPANY  
into var_NumRec;
```

When we use Execute immediate,  we should put INTO outside the statement..
Hope this will work for you.

Comment: This is not working for me, Getting error                         PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ORDER" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
   member submultiset

Comment: And I tried like below too..  
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||' into var_NumRec where COMPANY = '||var_company||' order by COMPANY'; 
Then I am getting error : 
"SQL command not properly ended"

Comment: Again getting error :
ORA-06550: line 11, column 97:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "ORDER" when expecting one of the following:

   . ( * @ % & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
   return returning <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <>
   and or like like2 like4 likec between into using || bulk
   member submultiset

Comment: Can you share complete pl sql procedure here , to find out what is in line 11 actually?

Comment: DECLARE
    var_NumRec NUMBER(15);
    var_Table VARCHAR2(40);
    var_company VARCHAR2(25) := 'ABC';
    TYPE my_nested_table IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(40);
    var_Direct my_nested_table := my_nested_table ('Employee', 'Accounts', 'FEE');
BEGIN
    FOR i IN 1.. var_direct.count
    LOOP
        var_Table := var_Direct(i);
        EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'select count(*) from '||var_Table||'  where COMPANY = '||var_company order by COMPANY 
        into var_NumRec;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ABC : '||var_NumRec); 
    END LOOP;    
END;
/